# Is it possible to run my app as if it was run on an older version of Android OS?

Tags: android, testing

I want my app to support older versions of Android, but my only Android device is of a much newer version.
Also, the emulator in the SDK is incredibly slow to launch and run.
I can't find any reliable testing environment for my app's functionality on older devices. Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [Remote test](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/remote-test-your-android-apps-with-these-services/1928)

or emulator is the only way.

You can build the app with limiting the SDK to use version hence conform that it will work on old device, then test it out thoroughly on your New device.

Fix some bugs and then run them on the old SDK Emulator or the remote setups.